# redis get the value from the result set

Tags: python, python-3.x, redis

I have result returned as from ZrangebyScore function as `[b'101']`. I would like to extract only `101` value and discard other additional characters. It is in byte form. How to convert it in Integer format using Python.

Comment: Looks like the function is return a list of `bytes`. So you just need to `decode` the bytes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using Py3 try this:

```
mylist = [b'101']
val = int(mylist[0].decode())
```